# Work with VisualStudio 2019 pro in domain

Tags: azure, dns, local

I need to setup VisualStudioPro2019 at school for teachers and students.
For work with projects after install using all the options of VisualStudioPro2019 is it needed that the schools' domain will be registered in DNS? If it will not be registered, would there be problems using Azure, Public Keys Certificate...?

To make my quastion more clear: my domain is "abc.local", setup VisualStudio on pc from domain controller. Different students will register on the same pc using ActiveDirectory of my domain. For using the functions of Azure they need to log in from browser?
Updates, ServicePack will be download to dc (domain controler), but my dcs' doesn't have a regestry in DNS (the domain is local). Is it possible to have a public keys certificate for local domain? Is it neccesary/mandatory?
In particullar, if it is relevant, the classes will be using Azure for developing applications.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio, its users and Azure functionality are completely independent of your domain setup. Users authenticate to Visual Studio and Azure with their personal subscription which *can* be a domain account federated with Azure but doesn't have to be.

The important point is, how users are authenticated to your organization Azure subscription and possibly to Azure DevOps if you intend to have your version control repository hosted there.